# The mean along the eccentric anomaly of an ellipse log distance to a point within the ellipse

Tags: integration, integral-geometry, multivariable-calculus

**Conjecture.**
Let 
$$ f(r,\alpha,p, \theta) = \ln\left(\left(r\sin\alpha-\sin\theta\right)^{2}\left(1-p\right)^{2}+\left(r\cos\alpha-\cos\theta\right)^{2}\left(1+p\right)^{2}\right). $$
Then for any real $|r|<1,\ |p|<1$ and $\alpha$
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(r,\alpha,p, \theta)d\theta\ =\ 0 .$$

The picture is the following: we have an ellipse with center in $(0,0)$ and semi-axes adding up to two and we have a point $P = \left((1-p)r\sin\alpha,\ (1+p)r\cos\alpha\right)$ within this ellipse. Then we measure the distance from from a point on the ellipse $\left((1-p)\sin\theta,\ (1+p)\cos\theta\right)$ to the point $P$ and realize that on average the log of this distance is zero. 
Also here is my [sketch on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vjdnts1lnq).
This fact sounds so  simple to me that I'd thought that someone else has already proven it.

Some of my thoughts on this:

For $r=p=0$ this is trivial.

For just $r=0$ I could prove it the following way: consider the derivative $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\partial_pf(0,\alpha,p, \theta)d\theta$ and through the substitution $t= \tan\theta$ get an integral of a rational function
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1+p-(1-p)t^2}{((1+p)^2+(1-p)^2t^2)(1+t^2)}dt
$$
that one can show to be 0 for any  $|p|<1$ and therefore the integral of the function $f(0,\alpha,p,\theta)$ itself must not depend on $p$, namely also be 0 as for $p=0$.

For $p=0$, just a circle and a point inside, the Pythagorean trigonometric identity applies and under the integral we basically have $\ln(1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\alpha))$, which after double angle $\theta=2\eta+\alpha-\pi$ substitution reduces to $\ln\left((1+r)^2\cos^2\eta+(1-r)^2\sin^2\eta\right)$, i.e. the previous case.

Here comes the feeling that the complete proof is somewhere very close, yet I completely stuck. Please share any ideas.

Comment: Is there some reason that you used the "elliptic-curve" tag? An elliptic curve is not an ellipse. The integral you've written is not an elliptic integral. If you don't know what an elliptic curve is, you should remove that tag. If you do, please edit your question to indicate how it is related to an elliptic curve.

Comment: presumably you want not only $|p|$ but also $|r|$ to be less than 1?

Otherwise $r=2$, $p=0$ gives $f=5-4\cos(\alpha-\theta)$ and the integral of $\log f$ over $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$ equals $4\pi\log 2$.

Comment: This is trivial. Just write the argument of logarithm as $$\left(1-p r e^{i a+i t}-r e^{i t-i a}+p e^{2 i t}\right) \left(1-p r e^{-i a-i t}-r e^{i a-i t}+p e^{-2 i t}\right),$$ where $a=\alpha$, $t=\theta$. From Fourier series expansion it is obvious that the integral will be $0$.